# SSH Connection refused after startup

Tags: ssh, connection

My office raspberry pi is used to run as a spotify player.  After reboots, it often takes a very long time before ssh allows me to connect.  Often I receive connection refused errors when my coworkers are able to ssh with no problems.  When I am having these problems, I am also unable to access the web page hosted by the pi, or any other services running on the pi, despite my coworkers having access to all of these services.

It has on occasion asked me for the username, and after typing in the user, refused connection without asking for pass.  Any ideas what may be causing this?

The pi has a static ip so I know this is not the problem.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2289/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6680            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9361/python
tcp6       0      0 :::6601                 :::*                    LISTEN      9361/python
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2289/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::6680                 :::*                    LISTEN      9361/python
```

Comment: Does it have a static or dynamic IP address? Are you accessing it using the IP address or the hostname?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact that your coworkers can access it and you can't, I believe this is possible a networking issue involving your workstation, rather than a raspberry pi issue.